# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': CordovaError: Uh oh

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

I had follow these steps to install an configure firebase to my cordova project for cloud messaging. https://medium.com/@felipepucinelli/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-your-cordova-application-using-firebase-69fac067e821

I have the google-services.json file and added into root path of my project. To install cordova-plugin-firebase, I tried to paste :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^2.0.0" />
```

into config.xml and run cordova platform add android@6.4.0 .

Output :

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': CordovaError: Uh oh!
"C:\Users\myAppName\application\platforms\android\google-services.json" already exists!
```

EDIT:
Tried step by step :

```
cordova platform rm android

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase --save

cordova plugins
com.unarin.cordova.beacon 3.6.1 "Proximity Beacon Plugin"
cordova-open-native-settings 1.5.1 "Native settings"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-barcodescanner 0.7.4 "BarcodeScanner"
cordova-plugin-bluetoothle 4.4.3 "Bluetooth LE"
cordova-plugin-call-number 1.0.1 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-email 1.2.7 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-open-blank 0.0.2 "Open Blank"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3-dev "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.0 "SocialSharing"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.6 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"

cordova platform add android@6.4.0

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --save
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': CordovaError: Uh oh!
"C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\res\values\colors.xml" already exists!
    at copyNewFile (C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\lib\pluginHandlers.js:245:45)
    at install (C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\lib\pluginHandlers.js:43:17)
    at ActionStack.process (C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ActionStack.js:56:25)
    at PluginManager.doOperation (C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\PluginManager.js:114:20)
    at PluginManager.addPlugin (C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\PluginManager.js:144:17)
    at C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:243:74
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:570:49
Uh oh!
"C:\Users\myProject\application\platforms\android\res\values\colors.xml" already exists!
```

I don't understant what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

according to [issue #25](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/25) ...

> in your `config.xml` first install `cordova-plugin-firebase` then `cordova-plugin-push-notification` or `phonegap-plugin-push`. make sure to first remove both plugins from plugins folder after removing platform.

this is because these two plugins clash, because both attempt to install that file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just for specify, cordova-android must be generate before install them ? Do I have to install them with the cordova CLI, to set them to the config.xml file or both are the same way ?

Comment: I tried to remove all and :
`cordova platform add android@6.4.0` : Success.

`cordova plugins cordova-plugin-firebase` : Error ->

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': CordovaError: Uh oh!
"C:\Users\projectName\application\platforms\android\res\values\colors.xml" already exists!`
Obviously cordova-plugin-push-notification is uninstall